# How to buiild LIBSVM on Visual Studio 2012, then scale training data

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, classification, libsvm

Could someone clarify the the instructions for "building windows binaries" for LIBSVM using Visual Studio 2012? They don't seem clear to me, especially for using command line tools.

Once I have built the LIBSVM binaries, how do I use them to scale my training data?

Answer (score 4):

To build the libsvm binaries:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\vcvars32.bat"
nmake -f Makefile.win  // in the libsvm folder
```

or open `libsvm-3.1.sln`, in the libsvm folder, and build. Your VS path may be different to the above.

If you are writing your own c++ code to use the libsvm library just add svm.cpp in your project and ensure that the include path has the location of svm.h. I strongly recommend you get comfortable with the provided command line tools before trying to write your own software, however.

To scale your data to the range [-1 +1], at the command line:

```
svm-scale -s scaling_params training_data_file > scaled_training_file
svm-scale -r scaling_params validation_data_file > scaled_validation_file
svm-scale -r scaling_params testing_data_file > scaled_testingfile
```

Note the use of the -s and -r parameters above. This is very important so that the same scaling gets applied to both the training and testing data.
If you must write your own software to do the scaling, the easiest thing to do is to look at the source code for svm-train and see how it does it (it is not hard).

**IMPORTANT:** carefuly read http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/guide/guide.pdf.
It will save you a lot of hurt.